# Using C# with C DLL for callback, can't get better than 16FPS framegrab rate, why?

Tags: c#, dll, camera

I have an application in C# that interfaces to a USB camera.  It's been working just fine except for the fact that I have not been able to achieve better than about 16 frames-per-second.  I'm using VFW, and a 'C' callback (the callback is part of a DLL) per `WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME_NOSTOP` message, and I've found that even if I do essentially NOTHING in the callback, I am unable to get a decent frame rate (16FPS is about the max).

I *thought* that using this interface would give me better performance than other alternatives (DirectShow for example) simply because of its simplicity and low-level connection to the driver; but now I'm beginning to wonder if that's true.
Anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Are you sure that the camera is capable of providing more than 16 FPS?

Comment: yes.  I've used other apps (of which I don't have source to) that get as much as 60FPS.

Comment: Did you try profiling to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: I didn't profile it (didn't know you could profile managed and unmanaged code); however, I isolated the code right down to the bone.  All it did was generate the callback, I wasn't even displaying the image and the framerate was still maxed out at 15FPS.  Regardless, using VideoInput has indirectly solved the problem.  Still, it would be nice to know why I couldn't get VFW above 15FPS.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find out why VFW appears to limit my frame rate; however, I found [VideoInput](https://github.com/ofTheo/videoInput) for C# and I now use that instead.  Gives me much more control over the camera and much higher framerates.

Answer (score 0):

Let me hazard a guess...

Are you using `System.Timers.Timer` by any chance? Or, is the C portion of the program using Windows Timer? If you do, its limited resolution might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: No, not for this part of the code at least. I have the code that does the WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME_NOSTOP message send in a separate thread, and even when I effectively null out the work I do in the callback function I still can't get above 16FPS. I've tried several different cameras too.   Actually, for testing this out, I've got the SendMessage(WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME_NOSTOP,0,0) in a loop and the callback doing nothing but incrementing a counter that I sample every second (to deteremin the FPS value).